# C3js charts do not cooperate well with Foundation reveal modal. Performance issue, want to find a workaround

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-reveal, c3

The **C3js** charts listen to `resize` event. It is good to get the chart responsive automatically, but I encountered severe performance issue when trying to coorperate the charts with the **Foundation reveal modal**.

As said in the github issue [Reveal modal triggers a resize event](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/6018), the reveal modal triggers `resize` event whenever a modal opens.

**C3js** charts are re-rendered each time the `resize` event is triggered. And it seems no way to prevent re-rendering the chart after the `resize` event using the api or callbacks provided by **C3js**. Therefore all **C3js** charts in the same page are unnecessarily redrawn each time a modal opens, and harms browsing experience.

Before **Foundation** change the way they handle the reveal modal in v6, is there any easy way to workaround this performance issue?

*The version used are C3-0.4.9 and foundation-5.5.1*